# Jasper Report nested subreport is not displayed

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports, jasper-plugin

I am using `Jasper Report` using `Java`.

I have

Main Report `contains` Sub Report `contains` Sub Report

The problem I am getting is that the main report shows the sub report but the sub report doesn't show its sub report.

```
mainReport.jrxml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version last-->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="demo" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="381b6277-2f70-46c8-9c37-6c8ac5f47857">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.1" value="pageHeader"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.2" value="pageFooter"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.summary" value="summary"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.1" value="pageHeader"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.2" value="pageFooter"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.keep.first.band.2" value="columnHeader"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.rows" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.columns" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.summary" value="summary"/>
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <parameter name="subreport" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport"/>
    <parameter name="title" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="username" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="logo" class="java.io.InputStream"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="resultEntities" class="java.util.List"/>
    <field name="sponsorName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="19b3ea11-765d-4e11-b823-6f2dffe149ef" x="200" y="2" width="310" height="30"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="18" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{title}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <image onErrorType="Blank">
                <reportElement uuid="827deabf-52f4-4e2d-a700-cb25e0d17f8d" x="0" y="-8" width="200" height="50"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{logo}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="17" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="21" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="130" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="e09c8f6a-0d7a-44a7-b050-5ae9e3d6cd1a" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="110" height="20" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Sponsor Name:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="5781f4ef-2af7-4144-82ff-27cc707099b7" x="120" y="0" width="277" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{sponsorName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement uuid="381339b0-ca91-41f6-a625-4281afd9e52a" x="0" y="80" width="551" height="46"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{resultEntities})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{subreport}]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="95763471-cdf9-4131-9496-05b9121ec189" x="120" y="20" width="277" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{username}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="08ea8903-a99a-4e09-84c4-012df07d73df" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="20" width="110" height="20" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Username:]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
        <band height="111">
            <break>
                <reportElement uuid="58154019-f6fe-4e30-bd85-e959cfb79c8c" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="4" width="100" height="1"/>
            </break>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="247f9650-33e1-49aa-9d48-2b53a63412ec" x="433" y="0" width="80" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement uuid="99aea93f-321e-49d5-84e9-356d3bf3d6a2" x="513" y="0" width="40" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
                <reportElement uuid="8be76444-ca98-43a1-be6e-8ccc5b581905" x="0" y="0" width="197" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="50" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="e09c8f6a-0d7a-44a7-b050-5ae9e3d6cd1a" x="80" y="20" width="330" height="30" forecolor="#008080"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" rotation="None" markup="styled">
                    <font size="18" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[End of Report]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

**Subreport-1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version last-->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="demo_address" pageWidth="555" pageHeight="802" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="5e467d97-e040-4786-bd94-5625de268971">
    <style name="Title" fontName="Arial" fontSize="26" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
    <style name="SubTitle" forecolor="#666666" fontName="Arial" fontSize="18"/>
    <style name="Column header" forecolor="#666666" fontName="Arial" fontSize="12" isBold="true"/>
    <style name="Detail" fontName="Arial" fontSize="12"/>
    <parameter name="subreport2" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport"/>
    <field name="iTID" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="allocationNumber" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="partDescription" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="serialNumber" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="partName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="stockType" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="dispatchLocation" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="partNumberSubEntities" class="java.util.List"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="5" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="50">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="0fd796af-139d-45ff-8eee-fad16f65c526" x="0" y="5" width="120" height="40" backcolor="#CFCFCF"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Proportional"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Option/Part No]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="231" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="77b324a2-4b82-4988-acf6-d93b68adfa1a" x="0" y="0" width="120" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Justified">
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Proportional"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{partName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement uuid="381339b0-ca91-41f6-a625-4281afd9e52a" positionType="Float" x="0" y="20" width="551" height="46"/>
                <subreportParameter name="subreport2"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{partNumberSubEntities})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{subreport2}]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

**Sub-Sub Report**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version last-->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="demo_address" pageWidth="555" pageHeight="802" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="5e467d97-e040-4786-bd94-5625de268971">
    <style name="Title" fontName="Arial" fontSize="26" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
    <style name="SubTitle" forecolor="#666666" fontName="Arial" fontSize="18"/>
    <style name="Column header" forecolor="#666666" fontName="Arial" fontSize="12" isBold="true"/>
    <style name="Detail" fontName="Arial" fontSize="12"/>
    <field name="iTID" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="allocationNumber" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="partDescription" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="serialNumber" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="partName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="stockType" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="dispatchLocation" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="partNumberSubEntities" class="java.util.List"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="5" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="50">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="0fd796af-139d-45ff-8eee-fad16f65c526" x="0" y="0" width="70" height="45" backcolor="#CFCFCF"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Proportional"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Stock Type]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="0fd796af-139d-45ff-8eee-fad16f65c526" x="70" y="0" width="80" height="45" backcolor="#CFCFCF"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Proportional"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Option/Part No]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="0fd796af-139d-45ff-8eee-fad16f65c526" x="150" y="0" width="86" height="45" backcolor="#CFCFCF"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Proportional"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Description]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="0fd796af-139d-45ff-8eee-fad16f65c526" x="236" y="0" width="60" height="45" backcolor="#CFCFCF"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Proportional"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[TID]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="0fd796af-139d-45ff-8eee-fad16f65c526" x="296" y="0" width="80" height="45" backcolor="#CFCFCF"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Proportional"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Serial No]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="0fd796af-139d-45ff-8eee-fad16f65c526" x="376" y="0" width="74" height="45" backcolor="#CFCFCF"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Proportional"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Allocation No]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="fb4084da-6bd7-4534-8f2e-bf13a976e52f" x="450" y="0" width="104" height="45" backcolor="#CFCFCF"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Proportional"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Dispatch Location]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="27" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="77b324a2-4b82-4988-acf6-d93b68adfa1a" x="0" y="0" width="70" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Proportional"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{stockType}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="77b324a2-4b82-4988-acf6-d93b68adfa1a" x="70" y="0" width="80" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Justified">
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Proportional"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{partName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="227" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

**Java code to export**

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("title", title);
        map.put("username", user);
        map.put("usergroup", usergroup);
        map.put("startDate", startDate);
        map.put("endDate", endDate);
        map.put("sponsorName", "Barclays");
        map.put("logo", GenericExporter.class.getResourceAsStream("/res/logo.gif"));

        // get collection datasource
        JRBeanCollectionDataSource jrBeanCollectionDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(resultObjects);
        // compile master and sub
        InputStream masterReportStream = GenericExporter.class.getResourceAsStream(masterReport.getFilename());
        InputStream subReportStream = GenericExporter.class.getResourceAsStream(subReport.getFilename());
        InputStream subsubstream = GenericExporter.class.getResourceAsStream("/res/DetailedStockReportSub_Sub.jrxml");

        JasperReport masterCompile = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JRXmlLoader.load(masterReportStream));
        JasperReport subCompiled = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JRXmlLoader.load(subReportStream));
        JasperReport subsubcompiled = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JRXmlLoader.load(subsubstream));

        // put sub report in map
        map.put("subreport", subCompiled);
        map.put("subreport2", subsubcompiled);

        // fill report
        JasperPrint jasperFillRepor = JasperFillManager.fillReport(masterCompile, map, jrBeanCollectionDataSource);




            JRPdfExporter jrPdfExporter = new JRPdfExporter();
            jrPdfExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperFillRepor);
            jrPdfExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, outpuStream);
            // run export
            jrPdfExporter.exportReport();

            return new ByteArrayInputStream(outpuStream.toByteArray());
```

Code executes fine , no problem. But if I look at the PDF it doesn't contain the table which is in sub-sub report.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Jasper` is crap. There is no proper control on the tables. It doesn't even work properly with sub-sub reports.

*I ended up using iTEXt , which is much better and you have more control how the data you want to display.*